# Angular Spring Oauth2 without sharing secret no Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have currently an Angular app which authenticates with Spring Oauth2, but currently I have clientID/secret on Front end side but I don't think this is very safe. How do I make it work without sending the client secret from Angular?